# SQL Server / 2 select in the same Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Here's what I'm trying do to in a single SQL Server procedure:

```
@ID1 int

select ID2 from TableA where ID1 = @ID1

(for each selected @ID2)
    select * from TableB where ID2 = @ID2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are your table structure and required output?  What, exactly are you trying to do, here?

Comment: Do you want a separate result set for each select from TableB, or are you okay with a single result set returned that includes all those rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That can be done in a single statement:

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM TABLE_B b
  JOIN TABLE_A a ON a.id2 = b.id2
 WHERE a.id1 = @ID1
```

But this means that there will be duplicates if more than one record in TABLE_A relates to a TABLE_B record.  In that situation, use EXISTS rather than adding DISTINCT to the previous query:

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM TABLE_B b
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM TABLE_A a
               WHERE a.id2 = b.id2
                 AND a.id1 = @ID1)
```

The IN clause is equivalent, but EXISTS will be faster if there are duplicates:

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM TABLE_B b
 WHERE b.id2 IN (SELECT a.id2
                   FROM TABLE_A a
                  WHERE a.id1 = @ID1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from TableB b where exists (select top 1 * from TableA a where a.ID2 = b.ID2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableB 
WHERE ID2 IN (SELECT ID2 FROM TableA WHERE ID1 = @ID1)
```

Generally speaking, you don't want to do any kind of looping in SQL Server. Try using "Set based" operations.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: The formatting is sucky for SQL, so I dont bother with it. If its really bugging you, you are free to edit the post.

Answer (score -2):

For each doesnt work in sql, you must use cursors.

```
declare @id int
declare @id2 int

declare mycursor cursor for
   select id2 from tablea where id=@id

open mycursor

fetch next from mycursor into @id2

while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin

   your code here

   fetch next from mycursor into @id2
 end
close mycursor
deallocate mycursor
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: No, i always use it and i never have problems with that, but, if he need a single clause, he can use exists or join clause, but cursors and forech do the same effect

Comment: Actually, yes - cursors **ARE** the work of the devil, if you have more than 5 concurrent users and more than 1'000 rows of data - don't use them

Comment: el-chente, Changing from loop to set based ops can reap untold magnitudes of performance increase (even for smaller sets), but may be a bit more difficult up front to implement.